# extract dataframes from list of dictionaries and combine into one

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries. Each item in the list is a dictionary. Each dictionary is a pair of key and value with the value being a data frame.

I would like to extract all the data frames and combine them into one.

I have tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

for both the full data file and for each dictionary in the list. 
This gives the following error:

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

I have also tried turning the dictionary into a list, then converting to a pd.DataFrame, i get:

```
KeyError: 0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give some examples of the input data? You may be able to do it without pandas. Are the nested dict lists all the same shape?

Comment: maybe `pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(d) for d in data.values()], keys=data.keys)`?

Comment: Trying pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(d) for d in data.values()], keys=data.keys) gives me the error  If using scalar values, you must pass an index.

Answer (score 0):

It should be doable with `pd.concat()`. Let's say you have a list of dictionaries `l`:

```
l = ( 
    {'a': pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape((3,3)))}, 
    {'b': pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape((3,3)))}, 
    {'c': pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape((3,3)))}   
)
```

You can feed dataframes from each dict in the list to `pd.concat()`:

```
df = pd.concat([[pd.DataFrame(df_) for df_ in dict_.values()][0] for dict_ in l])
```

In my example all data frames have the same number of columns, so the result has 9 x 3 shape. If your dataframes have different columns the output will be malformed and required extra steps to process.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {'d1': pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': ['one', 'two', 'three']})}
dict2 = {'d2': pd.DataFrame({'a': [4,5,6], 'b': ['four', 'five', 'six']})}
dict3 = {'d3': pd.DataFrame({'a': [7,8,9], 'b': ['seven', 'eigth', 'nine']})}

# dicts list. you would start from here
dicts_list = [dict1, dict2, dict3]

dict_counter = 0
for _dict in dicts_list:

    aux_df = list(_dict.values())[0]
    if dict_counter == 0:
        df = aux_df
    else:
        df = df.append(aux_df)

    dict_counter += 1

# Reseting and dropping old index
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
```

Just out of curiosity: Why are your sub-dataframes already included in a dictionary? An easy way of creating a dataframe from dictionaries is just building a list of dictionaries and then calling `pd.DataFrame(list_with_dicts)`. If the keys are the same across all dictionaries, it should work. Just a suggestion from my side. Something like this:

```
list_with_dicts = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 5, 'b': 4}, ...]

# my_df -> DataFrame with columns [a, b] and two rows with the values in the dict.
my_df = pd.DataFrame(list_with_dicts)
```

Comment: I wish i knew, this isn't my data.